# django сохранение изображения

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. Пишу api для приложения на django. Так вот приложения в request.POST отправляет изображения. Как ее сохранить в ImageField? В интернете все примеры сохранение из формы.

Comment: Изображения ну вообще никак не могут приходить в request.POST. Похоже, вы что-то не договариваете; покажите содержимое ваших request.POST и request.FILES, иначе мы ответить теперь не сможем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы можете использовать base64 , посмотрите здесь http://blog.mathocr.com/2017/06/25/store-base64-images-with-Django-REST-framework.html

Answer (score 0):

Загрузка нескольких файлов:

```
for image in request.FILES.getlist('gallery'): # gallery - название поля, в котором передаются файлы
    Gallery.objects.create(imgobject=image) # Gallery - модель, imgobject - ImageField
```

Загрузка одного файла:

```
Gallery.objects.create(imgobject=request.FILES.get('first_image'))
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Изображения приходит в request.POST.get("image_one"). И при попытке также сохранить в поле место пути к изображению появляются непонятные символы

Comment: @user8978194 Когда Django обрабатывает загрузку файла, данные файла попадают в `request.FILES`, следовательно туда и надо обращаться для получения контента. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#file-uploads

Comment: У меня эти данные приходит в пост. Это не сайт а rest api

Comment: @user8978194 http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser